# Editable combo is not properly binding to model property

Tags: data-binding, swt, eclipse-rcp, jface, rcp

I am using org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Combo which is not read only, meaning a user can insert any string or may select from the dropdown box.
But when I bind it to my model class property I get Null Pointer Exception whenever I am entering any text which is not present in the combo.

```
databindingContext.bindValue(WidgetProperties.singleSelectionIndex().observe(ComboReporterId), 
        BeansObservables.observeValue(Model, TextReporter_M));
```

Please help on this issue.

Comment: Getting null where? The selection index is not going to be useful if you are allowing text to be entered.

Comment: Hi @greg-449 could you please share something on this as I am new in this technology.

Answer (score 1):

For a Combo where text can be entered you will need to observe the text:

```
IObservableValue targetOV = WidgetProperties.text().observe(combo);
```

You will have to bind this to a value that is a String (or use a Converter).